# what does it mean before a variable in Java class @XmlElement(nillable = true)

Tags: java, xml

What does it mean before a variable in Java class    `@XmlElement(nillable = true)`. Does it mean that the field in xml is    optional?
       for example: `@XmlElement(nillable = true) protected String name;`

Comment: means name can be null

Answer (score 3):

`nillable` is a [XML schema element](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp):

> **nillable**: Optional. **Specifies whether an explicit null value can be assigned to the element**. True enables an instance of the element to have the null attribute set to true. The null attribute is defined as part of the XML Schema namespace for instances. Default is false.

So:

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true) protected String name;
```

Means you can assign `null` to variable `name`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it is

Answer (score 1):

It means it will allow a `null` value in the field.

Answer (score 1):

The `nillable` option means that a `null` value will be represented using the `xsi:nil` mechanism:

```
<name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

but it is unusual for an element in JAXB to be *both* nillable *and* optional (`@XmlElement` has a `required` option but it is `false` by default).  Usually you would mark a particular element as either plain `@XmlElement` (not required, so Java `null` means no element in the XML) or as `@XmlElement(nillable = true, required = true)` (required, so Java `null` means an XML element with `xsi:nil="true"`).

If an element is both nillable and optional then it would normally have to be a `JAXBElement<String>` instead of just `String`, to distinguish between a missing element (a `null` JAXBElement) and one which is present but "nil" (a non-null JAXBElement whose `isNil()` returns `true`).